# Strange groups of bars resembling vertical equal signs temporarily appearing on computer screen

Tags: windows-8

About three times per hour, groups of bars resembling vertical equal signs appear on either of the screens in my dual monitor setup, every time in a different location. They seem to disappear when I move my mouse to that area. I am using Windows 8. I don't recall making any software changes or updates prior to these bars appearing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some code is probably writing in your graphics memory. It could be malign, it could be an old software that has issues understanding modern address space layout, or it could be your graphics card or memory is faulty.